# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read' when reading from JSON data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, tuples, urllib

So, it's weird.  I am trying to get a script to run on my RaspberryPi to get weather data from a JSON stream from weatherunderground.  I am working in Python3.5 on a new Raspberry Pi on the latest Raspbian-Stretch OS.  It works when running on other machines (windows via VisualStudio and another Raspberry Pi running same distribution and an Onion Omega2 on LEDES distribution)

The lines that I am reading on (edited from other searches on this site) is:

```
import urllib.request
import json

# Get and load the weather data from my house weather station.
weatherdata = urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://api.wunderground.com/api/<myAPIKey-hidden here>/conditions/q/pws:KKYLOUIS68.json")
weatherinfo = json.loads(weatherdata.read())
```

The return from the shell is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/myweather_win.py", line 18, in <module>
    weatherinfo = json.loads(weatherdata.read())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I am not a programmer, just trying to learn and this has me stumped because it is working on other systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RafaelC said, you should use `urlopen` instead.
However, there is something wrong with RafaelC's code.
Since I cannot add a comment to his answer, I post it as a answer.
`weatherdata.read()` returns bytes object instead of string, 
so we have to convert it with `.decode()`:

```
weatherdata = urllib.request.urlopen("http://api.wunderground.com/api/c8659b546235193f/conditions/q/pws:KKYLOUIS68.json")
content = weatherdata.read()
json.loads(content.decode())
```

Tested on: Python 3.4.9, CentOS 7.6.1810

Comment: Thanks, that works now.  Now I need to clean up some of the calls from the JSON.  But it is reading and formatting as I need it to now.  Thanks, big time.  Lots of learning in the future for me.

Comment: Again, thanks.  Got everything pulling in correctly now had an extra ")" in one of the lines.  Now, to start adding in the LCD calls to print the data to the LCD, and eventually epaper display.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) instead of `urlretrieve`

```
weatherdata = urllib.request.urlopen("http://api.wunderground.com/api/c8659b546235193f/conditions/q/pws:KKYLOUIS68.json")
json.loads(weatherdata.read())
```

Comment: Now I am getting the following:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/myweather_win.py", line 16, in <module>
    weatherinfo = json.loads(weatherdata.read())
        File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
            s.__class__.__name__))
    TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Comment: @AdventuresOfRaven Please make sure to run exactly these lines of code. Cannot reproduce your error ;)

Comment: so how then do I add the JSON data to a variable?  I am actually calling 3 different URL's for different data sets in order to read and write what I need to the screen (later LCD).  I have to put the json.loads(weatherdata.read()) somewhere.  Like I said, it work in other setups, just not on this Pi.

Comment: I have tried running it with python3 and python3.5.  Python2 and Python2.7 still gives the original error.  I'll keep digging.